# Cast IEnumerable to custom ObservableCollection Class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

Is it possible to convert IEnumerable to a Custom Class that is inherting from ObservableCollection class?

Reason is I want to select only a filtered set of items on the **get**. I want to implement it on the **get** because lots of other properties reference **CustomItems** and perform processes on the items, but I want to somehow make it process filtered set of items depending if a value is enabled or not.

Below is code to help explain what I want to achieve:

```
public class CustomItemsCollection : ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>
{
    public ListView ListView { get; set; }
    public void ScrollToItem(object item = null)
    {
        //Some custom Code
    }
}
```

And here is my property that I want to customize:

```
private CustomItemsCollection _CustomItems = null;
    [JsonProperty]
    public CustomItemsCollection CustomItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (_CustomItems != null)
            {
                if(SomeValueIsEnabled)
                {
                    var filteredItems = _CustomItems.Where(c => c.Property.equals(SomeValue));
                    var castedItems = (CustomItemsCollection)filteredItems;
                    return castedItems;
                }
                return _CustomItems;
            }

            _CustomItems = new CustomItemsCollection();
            _CustomItemsChangedSource = new CollectionChangedWeakEventSource();
            _CustomItemsChangedSource.SetEventSource(_CustomItems);
            _CustomItemsChangedSource.CollectionChanged += _CustomItemsChangedSource_CollectionChanged;
            return _CustomItems;
        }
        set { _CustomItems = value; RaisePropertyChanged("CustomItems"); }
    }
```

Specifically, this part:

```
if(SomeValueIsEnabled)
{
    var filteredItems = _CustomItems.Where(c => c.Property.equals(SomeValue));
    var castedItems = (CustomItemsCollection)filteredItems;
    return castedItems;
}
```

Is this possible / or maybe wrong? What is the best practice to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just *cast* it, but you can create an instance of `CustomItemsCollection` and initialize it with `filteredItems`.

Add a constructor to your custom class that passes through to the [appropriate ObservableCollection constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx):

```
public class CustomItemsCollection : ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>
{
    public CustomItemsCollection(IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> items)
        : base(items) { }

   // your other code here
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var filteredItems = _CustomItems.Where(c => c.Property.equals(SomeValue));
var collection = new CustomItemsCollection(filteredItems);
return collection;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Are there possible memory leaks of creating the new CustomItemsCollection everytime the CustomItems is queried?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be any leak. The GC will clean up as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
 var filteredItems = _CustomItems.Where(c => c.Property.equals(SomeValue))
.Select(pre=> new ItemViewModel(){
//add info here
});
var castedItems = new CustomItemsCollection(filteredItems);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it though it showed an error for me on the .Select.